# Converting nested lists to org-mode lists

Tags: org-mode, list, header-line

I need to convert all nested lists present in buffer to org-mode headers using elisp. How can I do this?

`1.2.7.2 Some Header Name` -> `**** Some Header Name`

Comment: You might have to be more explicit about how the lists are labeled. Are they nested with period-separated numbers, and you want the org-mode indentation level to be the same amount as how many numbers there are in the input?

Comment: Yes, exactly like you explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty function to do the conversion - it just looks for lines starting with up to 4 numbers. Paste it into your *scratch* buffer, type <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> after it, switch to the buffer to convert, then enter <kbd>M-x convert-headers</kbd>.

```
(defun convert-headers ()
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (replace-regexp "^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+ " "**** ")
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (replace-regexp "^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+ " "*** ")
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (replace-regexp "^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+ " "** ")
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (replace-regexp "^[0-9]+ " "* "))
```